# API Mikrotik PHP

Tags: mikrotik

Кто может поделиться API Mikrotik для смены Firewal => Filter Rules средствами php
Хочу в фильтре через вебку на php менять айпи адресс в правиле
Может кто подкинуть апи или натолкнуть на правильную мысль примером?

Answer (score 0):

Один из возможных клиентов можно найти на [официальной Wiki](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_package).

Само описание API находится [там же](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API).

Чтобы изменить Filter Rule потребуется запрос типа этого, он отключает правило с ID *27:

```
/ip/firewall/filter/set
=disabled=true
=.id=*27
```

Чтобы узнать ID правила, можно воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
/ip/firewall/filter/print
=.proplist=.id,comment
```

Он вернёт ID и комментарий для всех правил.

Answer (score -1):

Я api использовал в php подобное, и писал интерфейс для этого, суть заключалось в управление несколькими микротами одновременно или единично, т.е. посылать запрос на изменение неких функций или иного к некоторым микротам, ну и вывод инфы! Тут можно почитать, что я делал, но код не выкладывал. https://vk.com/mikroconnect [image: введите сюда описание изображения]